# Trabalhando com arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho este array:

```
{tag: "teste"}
```

como faço para guardar a palavra teste em uma variável?

Comment: Cara, isso é um objeto js, na verdade se você quiser acessar essa variável basta colocar um ponto concatenado ao nome da variável e o key que vc está usando no caso tag.  então vamos supor que vc tem obj = {tag: "teste"}; vc pode atribuir a outra variavel com; var = obj.tag;

Comment: Aprenda mais sobre **ARRAYS** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array e sobre **OBJETOS** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos

Answer (score 1):

Isto `{tag: "teste"}` é um objeto json, e não uma array. Se você recebe um objeto chamdo xpto com este valor, então apenas busque pelo nome do campo: `var a = xpto.tag`. 
Abraços e segue o líder.